# Mouse and speaker disconnect and reconnect

Tags: windows-7, usb, audio, mouse, speakers

My mouse and speakers disconnect and reconnect at random (the connect/disconnect sounds from Windows will play), this happens regularly. Sometimes it happens every 5 minutes, other times it happens once every other hour.

The fact that it is both the mouse and the speakers make my think that it's a software issue rather than a hardware issue, but I have no idea how to go about diagnosing the problem.

I have already disabled Power Management in the USB Root Hub, to no avail.

Ideally I would prefer not to format the computer, but I will if needs be.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance
Willem

**PC Specs:**
Windows 7 Ultimate
Intel Core i5 6400
Gigabyte B150 D3H
Corsair Vengance DDR4 8GB 2400MHZ
Gigabyte Nvidia GTX 960 OC Edition 2048MB
Transcend SSD 370

Comment: External mouse? Also, why do you believe the speakers are disconnecting?

Comment: Yes, a USB mouse, this is a desktop. The speakers cut off and I get a Window popup saying that I've unplugged an audio device, then the sound comes back. Same problem as with the mouse.

Comment: I wonder if there is only one problem, because the mouse is a USB device but audio isn't. The popup for the mouse should indicate a USB device was disconnected. Have you tried another mouse? Or disconnect the mouse with some audio playing and see if the audio still cuts out?